# jquery anonymous function part 2

Tags: jquery, function

I have the following bit of code, and I am getting an 'anonymous function' function in safari... can anyone shed some light please?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('ul.nav').toggleClass('dropmenu');
    $('.nav_menu > ul').dropmenu({
        effect : 'slide',
        speed : 250,
        timeout : 0,
     });
 });
```

It seems to be pointing at `timeout :0`,

Comment: Remove the `,` after the line `timeout : 0,`.

Comment: Remove comma after `timeout: 0`. What does `dropmenu` method stand for?

Comment: @VisioN it is a JS Function that is part of twitter's bootstrap libary http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#dropdowns

Comment: its a navigation menu that 'drops down' to show the sub level of nag - i Hope! thanks

Answer (score 0):

you have an error in your code. The trailing `,` (comma) after `timeout : 0`

The anonymous function is started in the first line of code in your example

```
$(document).ready(function() { //<-- anonymous function
    $('ul.nav').toggleClass('dropmenu');

    $('.nav_menu > ul').dropmenu({
        effect: 'slide',
        speed: 250,
        timeout: 0
    });
});​
```

stack traces with a lot of anonymous functions might be hard to follow an it might be worth the few extra keystrokes to name your functions

```
$(document).ready(function showDropMenu() {
    $('ul.nav').toggleClass('dropmenu');

    $('.nav_menu > ul').dropmenu({
        effect: 'slide',
        speed: 250,
        timeout: 0
    });
});​
```

That way the debugger will be able to use the name of the function rather than simply "anonymous function"

In might also be a good idea in the outer most function to write `"use strict";` as the first line. This will tell the interpreter to fail on certain common mistakes making it easier for you to debug